How do I forward Chrome keyboard shortcut available to a Cockpit web terminal?
I am using cscope on Cockpit web terminal to browse a source code. The Ctrl+T shortcut used to unwind the tag stack is captured by Chrome/Mozilla, which then opens new tabs. Even if I remap the said shortcut to something common, like Ctrl+K, that too gets captured by the browser. How do I forward the browser keyboard shortcuts Cockpit? I used a few browser plugins that disable the keyboard shortcuts, but then those plugins suppress the shortcut altogether, neither forwarding to the browser, nor to Cockpit. Hence, those are useless.

Tried using several Chrome plugins, none works
Tried switching browser from Chrome to Mozilla
Tried changing keyboard bindings
None of the solutions captures and forwards (passes through) the keyboard shortcuts to Cockpit

